# Why does my view render the login page when logged in and re-opening my page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

First off, I'm struggling to grasp the concept of routing. I do understand the meaning of it, but cannot seem to understand what is happening.

I'm working on an ASP.NET Mvc5 project, where a login page is part of the system. The login page works fine when logging in the first time. However, if when logged in I close my browser and reopen the page it now renders the master layout with the login page as the rendered body.

These are my `routings`:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute("LoginPage", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
            {
                controller = "Login",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
                );

            routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
            {
                controller = "FleetList",
                action = "FleetList",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
                );
        }
```

And this is my `_ViewStart.cshtml`

```
@{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AnonymousUserLayout.cshtml";
    }
}
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your routes are the same so the engine uses the first one which matches the parameters.
You should define new routes only for those controllers/actions with different behaviors:

```
routes.MapRoute("ApplicationFetchBanner",
    "Application/FetchBanner/{fileName}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Application",
        action = "FetchBanner",
        fileName = ""
    }
);
```

Here I am defining a route which only expects one parameter `{fileName}` where the `controller/action` is well known.

For a complete explanation you can find [loads](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=814) of [articles](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC) written.

If you want to define a different layout for a page the best approach is to tell your view which one to use.

If I want to use a specific layout when the user is authenticated I would create two layouts, as you did.

The default one defined in `_ViewStart.cshtml` should be:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AnonymousUserLayout.cshtml";
}
```

then in your authorized page I would define the layout to use.
Your `Index.cshtml` will use non-anonymous layout:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

*Just use this definition at the beginning of your page.*

You can control the authentication in your controller using the `[Authorize]` attribute or `[AllowAnonymous]` on your action/controller.

A good article to read about authentication and authorization can be found [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/04/18/asp-net-mvc-authentication-global-authentication-and-allow-anonymous.aspx).

UPDATE:

I gave you the option which I prefer most cause you're able to control each view.
Another option is to customize your `_ViewStart.cshtml`:

```
@{
    string layout = "";

    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    else
    {
        layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MyLayout.cshtml";
    }

    Layout = layout;
}
```

There's a 3rd option. You can specify the layout when rendering a view in your controller:

```
return View("Index", "_AdminLayout", model);
```

... and a 4th one consist to include a `_Layout.cshtml` in controller's folder.

Comment: Completely forgot this one. I'm not really sure I'm able to grasp this, despite your answer. Can I not just have the _Layout.cshtml displayed if the user is authorized? Seems cumbersome to include the layout in every single view when the only view using the _AnonymousUserLayout.cshtml is the login screen.

I just cannot seem to get this routing definition to work either. Makes absolutely no sense to me :(

Comment: I've updated my answer but remember you have to use the attributes `[Authorize]` and `[AllowAnonymous]` if you want to manage who is going to have access to your controllers/actions.

Comment: Thanks, @leftyx for your suggestions! Since Login is the only page not using _Layout, I ended up giving that the `@{Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AnonymousUserLayout.cshtml";}` statement, as well as redirecting from that view if Request.IsAuthenticated is set to true. Also removed one routing rule, as they were doing the same, as per your answer :)